# Why does the stereographic projection of $ x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2=1$ need two charts to cover it instead of 1?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $$ S_1^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2=1\},$$ and $N = (0,0,2) $ be the North Pole of this sphere.

The map  $ \pi: S_1^2 \setminus N \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2 $ such that

$$ \pi (x,y,z) = \left(\frac{2x}{2-z},\frac{2y}{2-z}\right),$$ is the stereographic projection of this sphere into the plane.

To me, and my lack of imagination, this map covers almost all of the sphere, except the north pole. Because, the whole sphere is above the $XY$ plane. I'm wondering what is my mistake at believing this, because I have a problem which says: "Find the other chart that covers the sphere."

When I proved that $\pi$ was the stereographic projection, my argument was $t = \frac{R}{r} = \frac{2}{2-z}$, by Thales theorem, and a simple algebraic manipulation. Maybe for the other chart I should propose $t = \frac{-R}{r} = \frac{-2}{2-z}$? And so the new chart, $\pi_2$, that does not include the South Pole should be

$$ \pi_2 (x,y,z) = \left(\frac{-2x}{2-z},\frac{-2y}{2-z}\right)?$$

I am not sure of this. If the equation of the sphere were $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2=1,$ it is clear to me that I should pick two charts, one that comes from using the North pole $(0,0,1)$, to project all positive values of the sphere, and the other would come from using the South Pole $(0,0, -1)$ to project the negative values of the sphere. But in the setup I was given, I would think that it is enough with 1 chart, and my only possibility for fixing my thought is the observation I gave above.

Thanks in advance for the corrections, if there are any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me, and my lack of imagination, this map covers almost all of the sphere, **except the north pole**.

You're right.  But that "except the north pole" is crucial!  It doesn't cover the whole sphere, since it doesn't cover the north pole and the north pole is a point on the sphere.  So all you need for your second chart is that it includes the north pole.

Comment: ok. So I think then, that I could pick an open set in the plane $XY,$  around $(0,0,0)$ and a chart $x$ that sends the image of $(0,0,0)$ to the North Pole. is this correct?

Comment: Sure, you could just take a vertical projection to the northern hemisphere, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The unit sphere is compact. If you could use a single chart, that would imply that $\mathbb R^2 $ is itself compact, as its homeomorphic image. We know , e.g., by Heine-Borel this is not the case.